# Programa que Diz quantos numeros repetidos tem na coluna e linha de uma matriz

Tags: c, array, matriz, comparação, syntax-error

Para simplificar, eu tenho que fazer esse ex:

**Escreva um programa que leia duas sequências de dez números inteiros e imprima na
tela quantos desses números estão presentes nas duas sequências e quantas ocorrências
há de números idênticos na mesma posição das duas sequência.
Por exemplo, para as seguintes sequências:
1 20 102 42 37 20 11 53 11 1
11 20 1000 1110 532 42 37 87 87 1
O programa deverá imprimir na tela:
Há 5 números presentes nas duas sequências
Há 2 ocorrências de números na mesma posição das duas sequências.

Note que os números 1, 20, 42, 37 e 11 aparecem nas duas sequências (5 números
comuns nas duas sequências). Na segunda posição de ambas as sequências temos o
número 20 e na última posição o número 1 (isto é, 2 ocorrências de números na mesma
posição).**

---

E aqui está meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int l,c,k,m,cRepetido,nRepetido,var[10],var2[10];
    int seq[2][10];
    nRepetido=0;
   cRepetido=0;
   int verificado[c];
   
   
    

    printf("Digite os numeros da sequencia 1 \n");
    for(l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(c=0;c<10;c++){
            printf("[%d][%d]\n",l,c);
            scanf("%d",&seq[l][c]);
        }
    }
    for(l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(c=0;c<10;c++){
            
            if(seq[0][l]==seq[1][c]&&var[c]!=seq[1][c]){
                var[c]=seq[l][c];
                nRepetido++;
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    for(l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(c=0;c<10;c++){
            if(seq[0][c]==seq[1][c]&&var2[c]!=seq[0][c]){
                var2[c]=seq[0][c];
                cRepetido++;
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    printf("Existem %d  Repetições nas linhas\n",nRepetido);
    printf("Existem %d Repeticoes nas Colunas",cRepetido);
   
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, você colocou o enunciado e o código que você fez até o momento. Qual é o problema do seu código? Facilite para quem irá te ajudar criando uma resposta. Tente criar uma pergunta mais genérica que não seja um "façam esse exercício para mim", assim outras pessoas podem se beneficiar da sua pergunta no futuro quando tiverem um problema parecido.

Comment: Você testa posição dos arrays `var` e `var2` sem ter atribuído nada a eles. O teste será contra lixo de memória. Note que números que eventualmente se repetem devem ser contados uma única vez.